# Building query: Distinct count

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I need help on generating a Oracle SQL query...

The thing is that I have the following table:

```
COL1  COL2  COL3
----------------
1     A     XXXX
1     B     LLLL
1     F     TTTT
5     B     GGGG
5     C     VVVV
7     D     FFFF
7     E     AAAA
7     S     SSSS
```

The thing is that I need a query to show all the columns plus an extra column to show the count of the different COL1 values.

In the example we have 3 different values for COL1 (1, 5 and 7)

So the query should show 3 in the extra column. Something like:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COUNT(DISTINCT COL1) DIFF_COUNT FROM TABLE1....


COL1  COL2  COL3  DIFF_COUNT
----------------------------
1     A     XXXX  3
1     B     LLLL  3
1     F     TTTT  3
5     B     GGGG  3
5     C     VVVV  3
7     D     FFFF  3
7     E     AAAA  3
7     S     SSSS  3
```

I have tried many ways and I know that maybe its as simple as a COUNT with the corresponding group by but i havent been able to achieve it due to the need of having to keep the COL2 and COL3 in the results.

Any help on it?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **COUNT() OVER()** analytic function along with **DISTINCT**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT t1.*,
  2         COUNT(distinct col1) OVER() DIFF_COUNT
  3  FROM t1;

      COL1 C COL3 DIFF_COUNT
---------- - ---- ----------
         1 A XXXX          3
         1 B LLLL          3
         1 F TTTT          3
         5 B GGGG          3
         5 C VVVV          3
         7 D FFFF          3
         7 E AAAA          3
         7 S SSSS          3

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Alternatively, without using analytic function, you could do it using a subquery as an **INLINE VIEW**:

```
SQL> SELECT t1.*,
  2    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM
  3      (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM t1
  4      )
  5    ) AS DIFF_COUNT
  6  FROM t1;

      COL1 C COL3 DIFF_COUNT
---------- - ---- ----------
         1 A XXXX          3
         1 B LLLL          3
         1 F TTTT          3
         5 B GGGG          3
         5 C VVVV          3
         7 D FFFF          3
         7 E AAAA          3
         7 S SSSS          3

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit! Looks good. The only thing is that I need it to count the number of different values. So DIFF_COUNT column should be always 3. As i am having 3 different values in COL1 it should show 3 as the result (something like a COUNT(DISTINCT COL1)) . If I would have values like (1,5,7 and 9) then the rsult of DIFF_COUNT column should be 4 for all the records...

Comment: Thanks Lalit! Working fine this way! :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is:

```
select col1, col2, col3, count(distinct col1) over() cnt from test
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7511d/1)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the rest of the query should do, you could work with a subquery?

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, (SELECT DISTINCT count(COL1) FROM TABLE1) AS DIFF_COUNT FROM TABLE1....
```

you could even use the subquery to make different results per line that way

Comment: Thanks Razieltje, the problem is that the table I am showing is the result of a huge query and I cannot duplicate it on a new subquery otherwise the maintainability of it would be hell :(

Comment: You could place the results of the query in a temporarytable and work further on that one?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
col1, 
col2, 
col3,       
count(col1) OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1) DIFF_COUNT
FROM table_tmp;



     COL1  COL2     COL3     DIFF_COUNT
---------- -----   ----     ----------
         1 A       XXXX          3
         1 B       LLLL          3
         1 F       TTTT          3
         5 B       GGGG          2
         5 C       VVVV          2
         7 D       FFFF          3
         7 E       AAAA          3
         7 S       SSSS          3
```

Comment: Thanks Samiul!. But as added in below comment from Lalit i would need all the values for DIFF_COUNT to be 3. Its about counting the number of different values in COL1 and not counting the number of ocurrences of each value ...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bad solution but seeing as you haven't gotten an answer yet and I was messing around and got something that pretty much is what you wanted I'll put it here anyways:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
  (SELECT count (*)
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1
                FROM t1)
  ) AS DIFF_COUNT
FROM t1
```

There are probably better solutions but this is the only one I could figure out
SQLFIDDLE if you want to check it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32578/36

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. That is my last option :) Don't want to add twice the table in the query. The thing in reality T1 is a complex query and repeating it would be horrible :)

Comment: yeah I figured as much but if you don't find any alternative, it's a 'solution'